# What would day and night look like in a circumbinary system?

Tags: science-based, astronomy, sunlight

[image]I've been thinking of using a binary model (a planet that rotates around two suns) for a possible story.

The specific model is a S-type planetary system, where the planet orbits the the primary star A (0.8 M☉), while the secondary B (0.6 M☉) orbits the primary at a distance of 385 AU. the planet orbits around primary A at a distance of 0.85 AU.

The question is: what would the day and night look like in a circumbinary system of this type, and how could its configuration significantly affect the climate and seasons of this planet?
[image]

Comment: At 385 AU the other binary star will look like a bright star in the night sky. It would be 40 times further than Pluto is from the Sun.

Comment: This isn't circumbinary, this is [the other kind]. [Source](https://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/150/binary.png)

Comment: @RonJohn It's an S-type. That means the planet orbits around one star that is itself in orbit around a barycenter with another star.

Comment: Can you draw us a diagram?

Comment: The word "circumbinary" needs to be in the question, since that's essential to the question (and it's a real word).

Comment: There would definitely be a gravitational pull.  The planet's orbit wouldn't be stable

Comment: The secondary star impact on the climate is extremly marginal at that distance.

Comment: Questions like this are asked frequently here.  I would be frankly surprised if this isn't a duplicate of a pre-existing question (but I haven't the time to search, search for "binary" and/or "diurnal cycle" or "day night cycle").  However, at the distances you suggest, there would be no impact on the planet at all.  @Samuel is correct.

Comment: @RonJohn, I looked into this a while ago.  I can't be sure without doing the math, but a ballpark estimate is that the orbit is stable -- it's close enough to the primary and the secondary is far enough away.

Answer (score 2):

If the secondary B (0.6 M☉) is 60% mass of Sun, we can assume it is a large [red dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_dwarf) with luminosity about 7.2% of Sun's luminosity. Its [absolute magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude) will be about 7.68. The distance is 385 AU, which gives us [apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) of about -11. for comparison, full Moon's magnitude is -12.90, top brightness Venus' magnitude is −4.89 and Sirius (the brightest star) is −1.47.

The nighttime effect on the planet would be like from another Moon, which appears seasonally and does not have phases.

Gravitational pull of the star B at this distance will be extremely weak and detectable only with scientific instruments.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has been very useful! By the way, the primary star due to the proximity would look bigger or a size similar to the sun?